# IParameterInspector and Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wcf

In My WCF Service Methods I have an attribute defined. 
This attribute class inherits from Attribute & IOperationBehavior and also adds  IParameterInspector behavior. 
IParameterInspector Instantiated class provides BeforeCall & AfterCall methods.

Problem: Any exceptions that are raised inside the method call from beforecall method are not caught.
I have tried couple of solutions including IError available but none of them have worked.

This is my code: 
Service Method:

```
    [OperationBehavior]
    [MyAuthorization(Role = Enums.PsoRoles.DiceQuote)]
    public List<Employee> GetEmployee(int eid)
    {
    try
    {
    return _empService.GetEmployee(eid);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    _logger.Error(ex);
    throw new FaultException(ex.Message, new FaultCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError.ToString()));
    }       
    }

    public class MyAuthorization : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new MyAuthorizationParameterInspector());
    } 

    public class MyAuthorizationParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    { ...  } 
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    { ... }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I am getting exceptions raised from inside the code that is being called from within BeforeCall method. I need to trap the exceptions somehow.

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: using IParameterInspector with beforecall & aftercall methods- try throwing an exception from inside the code that is being called from beforecall.

Comment: Not being able to throw from there?